pygit2 equivalent of `git checkout -B`
I want to switch branch of a repository, or create it if it does not exists. Thus the equivalent of:
git checkout -B BRANCH_NAME

The repository may exist, or has just been created with
repo = init_repository(GIT_DIRECTORY, initial_head=BRANCH_NAME)

Thus, the repository may or may not have any commits yet. And note that if the repository did exist, init_repository does not switch branch, even if the branch existed.
My attempt so far:
The repo.checkout(BRANCH_NAME, STRATEGY_FLAGS) method does not seem to have the option to create a branch, also not in the CheckoutStrategy flags.
My second attempt was to use repo.set_head(BRANCH_NAME), but that gives a ValueError: the given reference name 'BRANCH_NAME' is not valid., Indeed, it seems that set_head() is a very low-level operation that actually can set the HEAD with repo.set_head(f'refs/heads/{BRANCH_NAME}'), but it does not create the new branch if it missing. When I attempt to do this, both repo.head.ref.name and repo.head.shorthand give a GitError: reference 'refs/heads/BRANCH_NAME' not found.
So I think I'm on the wrong track. Any help is appreciated.

Possible answer here: https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/issues/992, but this seems overly complicated at first sight.
